# Parsing JSON to get Google Reader Label information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, google-reader

I am trying to make a google reader app. I am able to get the subscription list in JSON format like this:

```
{"subscriptions":[{"id":"feed/http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/index_rss","title":"ActiveState Code: Python recipes","categories":[{"id":"user/014533032765194560dwd0/label/Programming","label":"Programming"}],"sortid":"E6312EFB","firstitemmsec":"1258141669516","htmlUrl":"http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/"},
```

I am interested in getting the label value (in the above case "Programming") into an array. Here is my current code:

```
-(BOOL)parsedSuccess {
     SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    if (!receivedData) {
        [self getSubscriptionList:GOOGLE_READER_SUBSCRIPTION_LIST];

    }
    NSMutableString *body = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (body) {
        NSArray *feeds = [parser objectWithString:body error:nil];
        NSDictionary *results = [body JSONValue];
        NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"subscriptions"];
        NSString *subTitles;

        for (NSDictionary *title in subs){
            subTitles = [title objectForKey:@"categories"];
                NSLog(@"%@",subTitles);
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Can someone help me in getting the label values?

Comment: Your code looks fine what seems to be the problem

Comment: Actually, I wanted to get one level deeper... after categories I needed to access label :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[[[[result valueforkey:@"subscription"]objectatindex:0]valueforkey:@"categories"]objectatindex:intvalue]valueforkey:@"label"];
```

I just helped to make logic. Be sure to check for spelling mistakes before implementing.